# Which of the following sets attached with an associated vector addition and scalar multiplication with real numbers describe a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Can you please help me with this question, I'm stuck and don't know how to prove it. Thanks.

Determine which of the following sets attached with an associated vector addition and scalar multiplication with real numbers describe a vector space. If any of these are not a vector space, show why at least axiom does not hold.

1) The set V containing vectors with two components (v1,v2) with regular vector addition and scalar multi- plication defined by c(v1, v2) = (cv2, cv1).

2) The subset V of M3×3 containing vectors made up of 3 × 3 matrices of the form
[image: matrix]

with regular matrix addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Have you written down the axioms for a vector space and started checking them? Which ones have you had trouble with?

Comment: I don't understand how to check it with c(v1,v2) = (cv2, cv1), because scalar multiplication of a vector supposed to output (cv1,cv2), right? Most likely I don't understand how this problem is stated (not a native speaker).